# App run failed after adding multi flavor configuration

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I add multi flavor configuration and after running the project I got below error.
[image]

How to fixe it please ?

Comment: Is your `MainActivity` is defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Proguard enabled or Dexguard enabled??

Comment: @Heisen-Berg I am using Android annotations librairy inside my activities or fragments so the generated Activity end with `_`  https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations . inside `AndroidManifest.xml` its `MainActivity_` not `MainActivity` . Everything works well before adding product flavor configuration.

Comment: @lib4 Proguard is correcty configure in gradle script.

Comment: Build gradle could u share?

Comment: @lib4 please follow this gist for gradle build script https://gist.github.com/pascalito007/f56926c3d293e242647e60d2af1be86c

Comment: Have you defined [source sets](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets) for your project flavors or is everything in `.../src/main`?

Comment: no everything is in `main` @BobSnyder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle) they say

```
// If you have different applicationIds for buildTypes or productFlavors uncomment this block.
//javaCompileOptions {
//    annotationProcessorOptions {
//        arguments = ["resourcePackageName": android.defaultConfig.applicationId]
//    }
//}
```

So I just add and uncomment these lines in gradle build script and then its works. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please make this change to your `build.gradle`, resync, and then clean the project before rebuilding:

```
flavorDimensions "tier"

productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "capstone.nanodegree.udacity.com.mypodcast.free"
        dimension "tier"
    }

    paid {
        applicationId "capstone.nanodegree.udacity.com.mypodcast.paid"
        dimension "tier"
    }
}
```